# Multiple image upload using MKNetworkKit

Tags: iphone, ios, mknetworkkit

I'm using MKNetworkKit to fetch server request. How to upload multiple image files using this JSON format?

```
"pictures": [
    {
        "name": "pic1",
        "qty": 1,
        "size": 312
    },
    {
        "name": "pic2",
        "qty": 2,
        "size": 123
    }
]
```

Most of the sample code Iv'e seen is:

```
MKNetworkOperation *op = [self.flUploadEngine postDataToServer:postParams path:@"/post.php"]
[op addFile:imageData1 forKey:@"firstImage"]; 
[op addFile:imageData2 forKey:@"secondImage"];
```

Thanks

Comment: You could simply serialize the image data as UTF-64 encoding and add it as a value with a key as you would any other primitive then deserialize on the servers end. But doing in the way you want described if I understand correctly will become a huge chunk of JSON and become slow very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSData *dataWithData1=UIImageJPEGRepresentation([ary_image_upload objectAtIndex:i],90);

    [self.flOperation addData:dataWithData1 forKey:@"userfl" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"fileName:imageName];
```

put the code try this